# Moving CALayer's mask on scroll in a Scrollview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage, core-animation, core-graphics

I am experimenting with iOS SDK and I have the following `UIView` structure:

- `UIView`

  - `UIImageView` - only a background image
  - `UIImageView` (with a `CALayer` mask)
  - `UIScrollView`

    - `Label`

Very simple structure, `UIScrollView` is transparent layer and second `UIImageView` has a mask on it. What I am trying to do is that `CALayer` mask would move its position according to position of the Content in the scroll view. If user scrolls, mask's position should be updated. I already solved this problem by using `UIScrollView`'s delegate:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    contentOffset.y = -contentOffset.y;
    
    self.overlayImageView.viewlayer.mask.position = contentOffset;
}
```

Mask is created in `viewDidLoad` and does not change during view controller's lifecycle.

**The problem is that the mask position updating is too slow.** That way it looks the mask is following the scroll view's content, not scrolling with it. The `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method is called correctly.

For you to better understand the problem, I am attaching a video I made in iOS simulator.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3xRl3LTngY

So the question is:

Is there a way to make mask updating faster or this is the limit of iOS?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

CALayer are implicit animated for some properties like position try to disable them:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

[CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
CGPoint contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
contentOffset.y = -contentOffset.y;

self.overlayImageView.viewlayer.mask.position = contentOffset;
[CATransaction commit];

}
```

Comment: Great, fixes the problem. Thank you very much. Mask position changes are much more fluid now.

Answer (score 0):

For me solution was as following:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
        layerGradient?.frame = scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame
        CATransaction.commit()
}
```